# Overlay view scroll as UITableView scrolls

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a overlay `UIView` above a `UITableview`. When I scroll the `UITableview`, I want the overlay  `UIView` to move at the same speed as `UITableview` scroll,just as the top menu of the facebook app.

[image]

Any suggestions?
I try to change the overlay uiview's frame in uitableview's scroll delegate.something like:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat offset = self.lastOffsetOfY - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGRect frame = self.overlayview.frame;
    frame.origin.y += offset;
    self.overlayview.frame = frame;
    self.lastOffsetOfY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

just use change of contentoffset value. but the overlay uiview doesn't move the same as the uitableview scroll.

Comment: I add some code of my way @H2CO3

Comment: Thanks. Just curious:is `self.lastOffsetOfY` initialized before presenting the views? Also, are there no scroll views that could interfere with this method? What if you put in a check like `if ([scrollView isEqual:tableView])`?

Comment: I initialized  `self.lastOffsetOfY` in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging ` and no other views except the same parent uiview

Comment: strange. I don't see anything wrong with the code. I'll try it a bit later.

Comment: Dear @keywind, you can add your `UIView` on the `superview` of `UITableview`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want that UIView to stick to the top of the screen at all times, independent of the tableview you just need to add the UIView to your controller's view instead of adding it to the tableview.

In your XIB, if you're using one, You should have something like

```
VIEW
    UITableView
    UIView
```

Instead of what you probably have:

```
VIEW
    UITableView
        UIView
```

Comment: yep..   it was in a tableviewcontroller and i was doing [self addSubview] so my overlay was a child of tableviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to accomplish an overlay similar to the Facebook app, it's going to be more efficient to add the overlay to the superview that houses your UITableView/ScollView. This way you won't need to write a bunch of code that needs to execute every time your user scrolls.

```
//in your View Controller:
UITableView *table = [[[UITableview alloc] init] autorelease];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake (tableOriginX, tableOriginY, width, height);
UIView *overlay = [[[UIView alloc] initWithDesieredFrame: frame] autorelease];
```

This way the view never moves, but gives the illusion of always existing at the top of the TableView. If, like facebook, you wish to dismiss the view, you can use the TableView's internal gesture recognizers to detect a flick (like facebook) that will dismiss or summon the overlay.

```
//Something like:
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
if (velocity.y > 0)
{
    [self hideButtonPannelData];
}
if (velocity.y  < -0.8)
{
    [self revealButtonPannelData];
}
```